# LVM Free Disk Space

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, mongodb

I have a MongoDB running on a  virtual server (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS). The MongoDB logs say this:

```
Fri May  8 13:08:02.270 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
Fri May  8 13:08:02.270 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /usr/lib/unifi/data/db/journal or use --smallfiles
Fri May  8 13:08:02.270 [initandlisten]
Fri May  8 13:08:02.270 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
```

So I expanded the virtual disk another 50GB, but I'm still getting the same message. I restarted both MongoDB and the machine itself. I added the "smallfiles" option in the MongoDB config. When I cycle through all of the LVM commands (`lvdisplay`, `pvdisplay`, and `vgdisplay`), they all seem to say that the disk is big enough.

What am I missing?

Comment: resizing the actual filesystem?

Comment: Please share the output of: pvs, vgs, lvs, df -h, mount

Comment: @JakovSosic Here are the outputs: http://pastebin.com/PUCPX4FE

Comment: @lmz is correct /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  6.5G  3.6G  2.7G  58% /

Answer (score 3):

From your pastebin output, I think you should try running:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

You can run this command without any downtime.